# No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my android app, there is an error while compiling the app. I am working in the latest android studio and using Firebase UI Auth and Firebase Database all the versions are in same in App level Grade file then why I am getting this error

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.dotndash.abjb.vishwakarmajanganna, PID: 7689
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.dotndash.abjb.vishwakarmajanganna-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                  at com.dotndash.abjb.vishwakarmajanganna.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:38)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

**Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Upgrade the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

also add:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

In the top level gradle file upgrade the google-service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

The firebaseui needs to be compatible with the firebase versions, check the following link for more information:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

These have been updated to the following:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
```