# QueryDocumentSnapshot cannot resolve

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`QueryDocumentSnapshot` is not cannot be resolving. I tried to change the versions of `firebase-firestore` and `firebase-core` dependencies but still doesn't work.

Here are the firebase imports:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
```

here are the dependencies

```
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

With the corresponding last versions:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
```

Be also sure to have:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

In your `build.gradle` (Project) file.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.dell.step-0EFkj52NpZr3iw4rjYmqKQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)

Comment: i tired this but it did help "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336198/no-virtual-method-zzbqoz-in-class-lcom-google-firebase-firebaseapp-or-its-sup"

Comment: In that case, please share the entire content of your both build.gradle files.

Comment: Don't mix versions, just use the one in my answer.

Comment: So please share the entire content of your both build.gradle files, as asked before.